# How does your ISP know how to identify your device?

Tags: networking, ip

Firstly, my network address range is 192.168.x.x/24. So anytime I start up my computer my IP address should randomly be assigned one of any 254 IP addresses on that network range correct? For some reason my ISP only allows me two be assigned one of two IP addresses on that range. Now onto my my real question. How is my ISP able to idenitfy my device when I connect it to my network. The only thing I can think of is my MAC address. However, when I changed my MAC address before connecting the PC to the internet the IP address showed up as the same as it always does. As far as I know my PC is not set as a static address. I am using linux and my network connections under Wifi in IPv4 it is set to automatic DHCP. The other preferences are: Manual, diable, shared to other computers and link local. When I change it to shared to other computers before connecting to the network it will not let me connect. So assuming everything is correct in my network connections, how is my ISP able to identify my device to assign the one of two address they have been assigning me?

Comment: How are you connected to your ISP? Physical cable or is this like a wireless ISP? Your ISP controls the hardware. Meaning they know what your modem is and what it is connected to. If you change your PC’s MAC address but that is meaningless. You can also change your router’s IP address and that is meaningless. For most ISPs the MAC address that matters is the media connection that connects the modem to the ISP. Like the coaxial cable connection in a cable modem. Or in a wireless modem, the cellular data connection. Changing that is pretty much impossible for end users.

Answer (score 4):

Most of your question is based on a misconception.

Your ISP doesn't assign in-house DHCP addresses, your router does.
It will assign from a pre-determined pool, though a lease time will have been set. If the lease is still valid you will be given the same IP address as last time. If it has expired, a new lease will be issued.

This is all determined by MAC address, by which your router identifies your machine. MAC addresses do not pass borders, so this information is not available to any device outside your own home network [unless the functionailty is built-into a program for security purposes. Some games do this to try to prevent multiple logins].

Some DHCP servers will assign whatever is free in the pool, with no further determination, simply random, others will attempt to maintain continuity. The router's internal software setup will determine which of those policies is used & that may not be user-configurable.